# How to manage my client's Facebook ads?

Tags: marketing, advertising

I wish to manage some of my client's Facebook campaigns and Google Ads campaigns. However, I don't want the responsibility of needing to manage those using their own accounts.

On Google, I'm planning on creating an email account for their use and using that email to create a campaign (which solves the problem. Their email is theirs, so if they choose to change to someone else, they can take the email address with them.

However, I'm not sure how this would work with Facebook ads.

How should I set this up? How do you normally deal with this? Am I right in not requesting access to the client's personal Facebook account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook actually allows you to set up a Business Manager account for the express purpose of managing pages and ads for yourself and for clients without needing personal page access. I just discovered this myself recently. [This page explains how it works](https://www.facebook.com/business/news/Business-Manager), and to access your account directly (once it's setup), simply visit https://business.facebook.com instead of the main Facebook log-in page.

You will need to request permission to manage pages that you do not own, so definitely notify your clients ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this workflow helps:

> 1. A simple **solution**:
>
>    1. Create a fake FB account (a personal one)
>    2. Like the contractor's page
>    3. Send him your FB email / password
>    4. Ask to be assigned as Editor (not an admin) in the Admin Roles of Facebook
> 2. When the account needs **funding** for the ad campaigns:
>
>    1. Your contractor changes the account password
>    2. Logs into the account
>    3. Deposits the funds
>    4. [Removes his payment method](https://www.facebook.com/help/132073386867900)
>    5. Changes back the old password
> 3. As a **result**:
>
>    1. You don't share any private data
>    2. You don't go over-budget
>    3. You can't "overtake" the FB page (you are an Editor, not an Admin)